# Is the isothermal isobaric ensemble suitable to describe systems with inhomogeneous pressures (e.g. the atmosphere)

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Let's consider a simplified atmosphere which can be described via a hydrostatic equilibrium:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_equilibrium
We therefore have a pressure which depends on the distance from the surface.
Does it make sense to describe this system in the NPT ensemble where a constant Pressure is assumed throughout the system? If yes how can the NPT ensemble deal with a spacially varying pressure due to an external field? Obviously the pressure is not constant...

Is the answer to this question related to the total pressure in Bernoulli's law? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_pressure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The appropriate set of constraints for the simplest equilibrium model of atmosphere where pressure varies with height is $T,N,g$, where $g$ is gravity acceleration. As a result of atmosphere having a mass, pressure will decrease with height, as the mass to be supported in gravity field decreases.